# Better regex for security and auditing?

Tags: php, regex, security

For personal use and work I have written various regular expressions to find all variables in PHP. The purpose of my regex is for security reasons and in particular to VET scripts and plugins. The expression is as follows:

```
\${1,1}[\w]+[" +"]{0,}=[" +"]{0,}['"][a-zA-Z0-9" "]+['"]+[;]{0,}
```

The above regular expression will find all `$vars` and what they are set to. I use it to search entire directories and sites using dreamweaver. The below is an example of what kind of PHP variables will be found with my above regex.

```
$var = 'sample';
$var = "sampletext"
$var="sampletext"
$$$var  = "sampletext"
$var      = "sampletext"
$var=     'sampletext';
$var = 'here is some sample text';
var = 'here is more sample text';
```

You can see how there is a slight variation to all of the above variables.  Some use double quotes, single quotes, some have semicolons others don't and there are also variations with spaces.

So, my question, can you simplify my regular expression?  Do you all have other regular expressions you use to VET and ANALYIZE any code, but PHP in particular would be nice. Many thanks for your time to read and help on this.

Comment: Your regex is actually looking for variable assignment expressions. Extracting those from source code correctly would require a way more complex and recursive pattern. In particular to eschew comment context, or escaped quotes in string literals, or to discover heredocs even. Feasible, but not reasonable. In short, you may want to look into [PHP_Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) instead to get a high-level representation.

Comment: Is this homework? This regex shows all signs of making it almost as long as possible. Furthermore it shows some problems with escaping characters in a string.

Comment: Furthermore who says you initialize a variable immediately. You can first *declare* it and later use it. For instance `$var; $var = 4;`

Comment: @CommuSoft `$var;` makes no sense, it's not a declaration (since there is no such in php) and it will trigger a notice.

Comment: @zerkms: sorry meant `global $var;`

Comment: @StephenCarr: are declarations without a semicolon allowed? The interactive `php -a` shell doesn't seem to like the idea very much...

Answer (score 3):

Both the regex in the *question* and *answer* look for *variable assignment expressions*; if you are only looking for the first assignment, this will complicate matters and you better - as @mario says - use the *`PHP_Parser`*.

There are a lot of weird aspects with this regex. First of all a small enumeration of weird regex constructs:

1. `\${1,1}`

   `{1,1}` means between *one* and *one* time. This is rather useless and can be replaced by `\$`.
2. `[\w]+`

   Here you use a box of only one type of characters, a semantically equivalent expression would be `\w`, but there is something wrong with this part. This [document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) says a the name of a variable can only start with a **letter or underscore**. Followed by **letters, underscores and digits**. `\w` means only the last category. Thus an expression like `$0` would be matched. The documentation however shows how to specify a variable name:

   ```
   [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
   ```
3. `[" +"]{0,}`

   Here I'm not entirely sure what you aim to do; you seem to provide the regex a choice of zero or more repititions of quotes (`"`), spaces () and plus (`+`). If you want zero or more spacing characters, you can use `\s*`. The same holds for the parts after the assignment.
4. `=`

   Here you assume that you can only declare a variable with an assignment. That's not true: PHP allows to use the default value and for instance write `$var += 3;`. In that case `$var` will be "*initialized*" with `3` since the default value is `0`. I agree this is bad design. Optionally you can allow it with `([+-*/%.&|^]|<<|>>)?`.
5. Spacing again; see number 4.
6. `['"][a-zA-Z0-9" "]+['"]+[;]{0,}`.

   Expression, it is hard to parse a PHP expression next of the assignment operator. It can be constants like numbers, but these can be variables, strings, function calls,... Function calls can even be cascaded in `f(1,2,g(3,'a'))`, etc. By standard regexes such calls cannot even be processed correctly: it is a consequence of the *pumping lemma for regular languages*. PHP however allows the *balanced brackets* extension so in theory it can be done. In that case, you will however need to dig into the context free grammar of PHP making it all harder.

   You furthermore state some of the expressions don't end with a semicolon. The `php -a` interactive shell however doesn't seem to like the idea very much:

   ```
   $ php -a
   php > $var
   php > echo $var;
   PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in php shell code on line 2
   ```

   You could use the *semi-colon* as a way to find out when the expression will terminate. For instance:

   ```
   .*?;
   ```

   This will work but there is a problem: a semicolon can be placed inside a string as well. In that case one needs to ignore the semicolon. You can replace the dot `.` with the regex:

   ```
   ([^"']|(["'][^"]*["']))*?
   ```

   But this again results in problems, because a quote can be escaped (like `"\""`) as well in; in that case you don't want the regex to interpret the second `"` as the end of the string. You can solve this by making the regex a bit more complicated:

   ```
   ([^"']|(["']([^"\\]|\\.)*["']))*?
   ```

As a result, the regex could read:

```
\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\s*([+-*/%.&|^]|<<|>>)?=\s*([^"']|(["']([^"\\]|\\.)*["']))*?;
```

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tN5bN8/1).

As said before this **requires the expression to end with a semicolon**. Semicolons in string environments are ignored.